# How to choose three points on the circle so that the triangle is not a right triangle?

Tags: geometry

I want to choose three points $A$, $B$, $C$ has integer coordinates on the circle $$(x+2)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 25$$ so that the triangle is not a right triangle. But I can not. I tried

```
ClearAll[a, b, r];
a = -2;
b = -1;
r = 5;
Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2, x != a, y != b}, {x, y}, Integers]
```

Comment: Choose them so no two are the end points of a diameter.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the solutions you already found, you can generate all possible triangles:

```
ss = Subsets[{x, y} /. 
       Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2, x != a, y != b}, {x, y}, Integers], 
       {3}
     ]
```

Now, select from those the ones not containing an angle of 90 degrees (with integers, *Mathematica* is smart enough to find exact right angles where they occur, so we can test for $\frac{\pi}{2}$):

```
res =
Pick[ss, 
     (FreeQ[#, π/2] &) /@ 
       ({VectorAngle[#2 - #1, #3 - #1], 
         VectorAngle[#1 - #2, #3 - #2], 
         VectorAngle[#1 - #3, #2 - #3]
        } & @@@ ss)
];
```

Display the 32 results:

```
Partition[
    Graphics[{Circle[{-2, -1}, 5], Polygon[#], Red, Point /@ ss}, 
              ImageSize -> {{80}, {80}}
    ] & /@ res, 
    8
] // Grid
```

[image]

The remaining 24 have a right angle, just put a `Not` in front of the `FreeQ` above to find them. Displaying that:

[image]

Comment: Maybe include `Circle[{-2, -1}, 5]` too, to facilitate visualization.

Comment: @J. M. I was too lazy, but I bit the bullet. Done.

Comment: How to list the coordinates of all this triangle (not a right triangle)?

Comment: Ok. res = Pick[
  ss, (FreeQ[#, \[Pi]/2] &) /@ ({VectorAngle[#2 - #1, #3 - #1], 
       VectorAngle[#1 - #2, #3 - #2], 
       VectorAngle[#1 - #3, #2 - #3]} & @@@ ss)]

Comment: @minthao_2011 The 2nd of my 3 lines of code, indeed. that wasn't so difficult, was it?

Comment: Yes. I did so. Thank you.

Comment: I want to copy the result to LaTeX. How to convert the output array to list?

Comment: @minthao_2011 `res//TeXForm`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9358/discussion-between-minthao-2011-and-sjoerd-c-de-vries)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, You said "The remaining 24 have a right angle, just put a Not in front of the FreeQ above to find them". I dont know how to put the FreeQ. Please write for me that command. Thank you.

Comment: @minthao_2011 Just put a `!` (which is shorthand for `Not`) in front of `FreeQ`, like `!FreeQ`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Edit

I have modified my code to honor the constraint that the chosen points must have integer coordinates.

---

I decided to see if,using only simple geometric notions, I could write a function generating a random triangle meeting the stated criterion each time it was called. Here is what I came up with:

First two auxiliary functions.

```
intPts[xy_, r_, n_] :=
  Module[{x, y},
    RandomSample[{x, y} /.
      Solve[(x - xy[[1]])^2 + (y - xy[[2]])^2 == r^2, Integers],
    n]]

notDiameterQ[{u_, v_}, r_, δ_] := EuclideanDistance[u, v] < (2 - δ) r
```

The first auxiliary function returns `n` points having Integer coordinates that lie on the circumference of a circle with center `xy` and radius `r` and such that they have integer coordinates.. The second tests for a line segment being less than a diameter of circle of radius `r`. It returns `True` if the distance between points `u` and `v` is less than a `2 r` by the amount `δ` and returns `False` otherwise.

The main function, `triangle`, returns three randomly selected points on a circle with center `xy` and having radius `r` and satisfying the constraints of having integer coordinates and not forming a right triangle.

```
triangle[xy_, r_] :=
  Module[{pts, pairs},
    pts = intPts[xy, r, 3];
    (* to test all three sides of the triangle, all three pairing of points are needed  *)
    pairs = Subsets[pts, {2}];
    (* if the points are OK, return them, otherwise try again *)
    If[And @@ (notDiameterQ[#, r, .05]& /@ pairs), pts, triangle[xy, r]]]

SeedRandom[4]; pts = triangle[{-2, -1}, 5];
Graphics[{Circle[{-2, -1}, 5], PointSize[Large], Point[{-2, -1}], Red,
   Point[pts]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> True]
```

[image: TriangleOnACircle.png]

Comment: What about the integer coordinates requirement?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Oops, missed that somehow. I'll look into fixing my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to implement the solution in a single `Solve`, all 960 of them.  The determinant is zero if the three points you get by dropping the 1's are colinear; if they are, they lie on a diagonal, and either the solution is a right triangle or two points are coincident (i.e. no triangle).  Dividing by the determinant rules out these cases.

```
circleRules = {r -> 5, a -> -2, b -> -1};
sols = Solve[{
  ((p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2 - r^2) /
     Det[ {{a, b, 1},
           {u, v, 1},
           {s, t, 1}} ] == 0,
  ((s - a)^2 + (t - b)^2 - r^2) /
     Det[ {{a, b, 1},
           {p, q, 1},
           {u, v, 1}} ] == 0,
  ((u - a)^2 + (v - b)^2 - r^2) /
     Det[ {{a, b, 1},
           {p, q, 1},
           {s, t, 1}} ] == 0} /. circleRules,
  {p, q, s, t, u, v}, Integers];
```

Here's a faster way to do the same thing:

```
sols2 = Solve[{(p - a)^2 + (q - b)^2 - r^2 == 0,
               (s - a)^2 + (t - b)^2 - r^2 == 0,
               (u - a)^2 + (v - b)^2 - r^2 == 0} /. circleRules,
              {p, q, s, t, u, v}, Integers];
figs = {{p, q}, {s, t}, {u, v}} /. # & /@ sols2;
nonRtTri2 =
  Pick[figs, 
       Unitize[Times @@ Flatten @
         Minors[Transpose[#~Append~{a, b} /. circleRules]~Append~{1, 1, 1, 1},
                3] & /@ figs],
       1];
```

Consistency:

```
nonRtTri = {{p, q}, {s, t}, {u, v}} /. # & /@ sols;
nonRtTri == nonRtTri2
  (* True *)
```

What they look like:

```
allPts = Union @ Flatten[{{p, q}, {s, t}, {u, v}} /. # & /@ sols, 1];
Graphics[{Circle[{a, b}, r] /. {r -> 5, a -> -2, b -> -1}, 
          Polygon[{{p, q}, {s, t}, {u, v}}] /. #, Red, Point[allPts]}, 
         ImageSize -> 80] & /@ sols;
```

[image: Triangle movie]

Comment: In his code, the OP seems to explicitely exclude the coordinates on the x and y axis. It is not clear to me whether or not this is part of the actual question.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thanks.  I was careless with that detail and just read the text.  I guess, thinking about it, I'm not sure whether the text or the code should be taken as definitive.

Answer (score 2):

First lets find the integer coordinates on your circle.

```
ClearAll[a, b, r];
a = -2;
b = -1;
r = 5;
points = {x, y} /.Solve[{(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2}, {x, y}, Integers];
```

Now you want to choose those points which doesn't form a right triangle. Since I don't know if you need a list of all possible points or any point, I will do a `RandomChoice`. You can put the whole thing in a loop to generate a set.

```
p1 = {x1, y1} = RandomChoice[points];
p2 = {x2, y2} = RandomChoice[Cases[points, Except[p1]]];
p3 = {x3, y3} = RandomChoice[Cases[points, Except[{p1, p2}]]];
R12 = (y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2;
R23 = (y3 - y2)^2 + (x3 - x2)^2;
R31 = (y1 - y3)^2 + (x1 - x3)^2;
If[R12 + R23 != R31 && R23 + R31 != R12 && R31 + R12 != R23, 
set = {p1, p2, p3},set=Null]
```

You can check the angles as well and the position of the triangle also

```
\[Theta]12 = ArcCos[(R23 + R31 - R12)/(2. Sqrt[R23 *R31])]*180/\[Pi];
\[Theta]23 = ArcCos[(R31 + R12 - R23)/(2. Sqrt[R31*R12])]*180/\[Pi];
\[Theta]31 = ArcCos[(R12 + R23 - R31)/(2. Sqrt[R12*R23])]*180/\[Pi];
Show[{ContourPlot[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2, {x, a - r, a + r}, {y,b - r, b + r}, PlotLabel -> {\[Theta]12, \[Theta]23, \[Theta]31}],Graphics[Polygon[set]]}]
```

If there is a Null output one of the angles will be 90. and you have to execute the loop again. Or you can use a loop.

**Alternatively** you can use the the angles (If[theta(i,j)!=90.&&...,set={p1,p2,p3}]) to filter out your desired set and then you can choose triangle with any angle.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, this is much faster than Solve..

```
Last@Last@
     Reap[Do[ If[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2 && x != a && y != b, 
     Sow[{x, y} ]], {y, -r + b, r + b}, {x, -r + a, r + a}]]
```

For a one line solution..

```
Graphics[{Circle[{a, b}, r], Polygon[#]}] & /@ 
     Select[ Subsets[ ( (
          Last@Last@Reap[
             Do[ If[(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2 && x != a && y != b, Sow[{x, y} ]],
                {y, -r + b, r + b}, {x, -r + a, r + a}]])), {3}] , 
                      And @@ ( Function[ pts, Mean[pts] != {a, b}] /@  
                             Subsets[#, {2}] ) & ]
```

Comment: Nice, but I think it should be pointed out that as `r` grows `Solve` eventually wins the speed contest.